# want to make a dnn module

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, dotnetnuke

i am New to dnn. i want to make a module of dnn in c#. I am trying but there is an error(he files '/cross/App_Code/AssemblyInfo.vb' and '/cross/App_Code/ADefHelpDesk/dnnHelpDeskDAL.designer.cs' use a different language, which is not allowed since they need to be compiled together).

how this Error Will be removed?

Answer (score 2):

Do the following in the web.config file. you have to **register your app_code subfolders to generate granular assemblies during compilation**.

Your app_code should contain a folder for your custom module which contains the buisnes logic and DB access layers.(refer creating custom modules in dnn)

```
    <system.web>
       <compilation>
     <!-- register your app_code subfolders to generate granular assemblies during compilation-->                                                                                    
              <codeSubDirectories>                      
          <add directoryName="ADefHelpDesk"/>
          </codeSubDirectories>
    </compilation>
      </system.web>
```

Hope this will help you..

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a code subdirectory element in your web.config file:

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <compilation>
         <codeSubDirectories>
           <add directoryName="ADefHelpDesk"/>               
         </codeSubDirectories>
      </compilation>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```